# Increasing paragraph indentation in KOMA script

Tags: spacing, indentation, paragraphs, koma-script, parskip

The default parindent in KOMA `scrartcl` is too small for me. I remember reading somewhere that just changing `\parindent` directly is not wise, since it also affects other things (like `itemize` etc). And I think I read that using something like the `parskip` package is better. Now, the [`parskip` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) documentation says that the KOMA script classes provide similar functionality. But I can't see where in the KOMA guide it discusses changing the indentation.

Does KOMA script offer a better way of doing this, or should I just modify parindent directly?

Comment: Changing `\parskip` (the vertical space between two paragraphs) is not wise (that's why the package is called `parskip` and why KOMA has a lot of `parskip` options). Changing `\parindent` (the horizontal space at the start of a paragraph) is not a problem.

Comment: @Ulrike D'oh. Should have thought more carefully before asking this. It did seem strange that KOMA has 8 options for parskip, but just the one for parindent! Could you put this as an answer? And perhaps explain why it is that playing with parskip is a bad idea?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The main reason why "playing with `\parskip` is a bad idea" is that this length also affects list environments. Quoting from Mittelbach (1989), [*With LateX into the Nineties*](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb10-4/tb26mitt.pdf), section 3.1 "Implementation desasters":

> The generic list environment is one of
>   the central modules of the LaTeX
>   implementation. It is used internally
>   by most standard environments provided
>   by LaTeX; even environments such as
>   `center` are handled as a special kind
>   of list [...]
>
> - An actual conceptual bug was the decision to add the value of `\parskip`
>     to all vertical spacing parameters,
>     even when it is used in places where
>     no paragraph ends. This means that
>     changing this parameter influences the
>     layout in unexpected places, which in
>     turn means that other parameters must
>     be adjusted unnecessarily to
>     compensate for this undesired side
>     effect.

The last sentence describes what the `parskip` package, the options of the same name of the `KOMA-script` classes and the `\abnormalparskip` macro of the `memoir` class do: Besides setting `\parskip` to a positive value (and, with the exception of `memoir`, setting `\parindent` to zero), they adjust the spacing before and after lists.

Why does `KOMA-script`have so many options for `parskip`? You may choose between a vertical space equal to `\baselineskip` (`full`) or `0.5\baselineskip` (`half`). You may also choose the minimum amount of whitespace to be left at the end of the last line of a paragraph (up to `0.33\linewidth`); such whitespace increases the perceptibility of the start of a new paragraph.

Regarding `\parindent`: As Ulrike has explained, changing this length is not a problem.

Comment: Presumably LaTeX3 will fix this "conceptual bug"?