# How to disable automatic indentation on new paragraphs?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I'm using a template that I can't/shouldn't modify. This template forces that every time a new paragraph begins, there is an indentation added. In some rare cases this is just looking really ugly and that's why I'd like to avoid this indentation. Is there any way to do this without changing the template?

Comment: Related question: [Increasing paragraph indentation in KOMA script](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13978/2975).

Comment: I don't see how the indent when starting a paragraph may look ugly. If this happens after some environment, e.g., a math display, just don't leave a blank line.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You can avoid the paragraph indention for specific paragraphs with the `\noindent` macro. If you want to disable it globally you could use `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`. However, I would not recommend changing it globally in your case, because that's effectively changes the template, even if the actual file isn't modified.

Comment: It might be useful to note that, if used inside curly brackets, `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` can disable indentation limited to the bracketed portion of the document.

Answer (score 121):

The `parskip` package turns off the indentation and adds a little bit of (stretchable) space in between paragraphs. It might be an option if you don't mind the inter-paragraph spacing. Simply add `\usepackage{parskip}` to your preamble to use the package. Martin's last sentence applies to this solution as well, of course.

Answer (score 8):

If you are working with a KOMA document class, I can also recommend to use the `parskip=full` option as it handles the spaces based on your wish to remove the paragraph indentation pretty well (adds vertical spacing between paragraphs, etc.).

Example: `\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}`.