# Indentation after '\tabular' environments

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, indentation

I was filling some tables for my progress report and noticed something were odd. The following text/tables are indented. MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = 1in, headheight = 12pt, includehead, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
 \section*{Section 1}
  \subsection*{Subsection 1}
   \begin{tabular}{ l l p{0.5cm} l l }
    TextText: & TextText & & TextText & TextText\\
    TextText & TextText & & TextText & TextText
   \end{tabular}
   \vspace{12pt}
   {\scriptsize{\bfseries{Little note!}}}
   \vspace{12pt}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X |}
    \hline
    \bfseries{Tabletitle}\\
    \hline
    \\ \\ \\
    \hline      
   \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Is that really the normal behaviour and is there any other way as `\begin{flushleft} ... \end{flushleft}` to remove the indentation a get the right alignment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn off indentation globally by adding `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` or if you only want to turn it of for the table add a `\noindent` before`\begin{..}`.
Compare also this post: [How to disable automatic indentation on new paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14375/how-to-disable-automatic-indentation-on-new-paragraphs)

Comment: Yeah I just remembered that I already used `\parindent0em` in one of my previous documents. -.-

Comment: `\parindent0em` has a bad effect on your document layout; at the least you need to set a non-zero `\parskip`, but that has its difficulties too.  personally, i would use `\noindent` before each thing whose indentation you need to suppress.

Answer (score 6):

The second table is in a new paragraph, so it gets indented. Putting `\noindent` before `\begin{tabularx}` well prevent its indentation.

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot. Sometimes I'm really daft. -.- I don't know, how I could miss that.