# \scalebox not working

Tags: tables

I can't figure out why scalebox isn't working. Here's the working example (uncomment the \scalebox line and the file doesn't compile. (I had trouble formatting the long lines).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xllll}
%\scalebox{.50}
\hline
Type of Violation & 1st & 2nd & 3rd & 4th \\
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
Presence without \\
justification, during\\ work hours\\
in an unauthorized\\place\end{tabular} & 10\% & 25\% & 50\% & 1 day \\    
\hline
Receiving non-work    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Written\\     Warning\end{tabular} & 10\%   & 15\%    & 25\%      \\
\hline
Personal use      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Written\\ 
Warning\end{tabular} & 10\%   & 25\%    & 50\%      \\
\hline
Interference   & 50\%      & 1 day  & 2 days   & 3 days    \\
\hline
Entry/Exit    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Written\\ 
Warning\end{tabular} & 10\%   & 15\%    & 25\%      \\

\end{tabularx}



\end{document}
```

**This question is about scaling/reducing an entire table in size. The answer at [Indentation after '\tabular' environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123229/indentation-after-tabular-environments) deals with INDENTING a table. This is NOT my issue.

Comment: It does not work, as the syntax is wrong, it should be `\scalebox{0.5}{text}` to scale the `text`. However, please don't scale a table. If you want it to be smaller use `\begin{tabularx}{.75\textwidth}{Xllll}` or similar. If you want a smaller fontsize, set it manually.

Comment: If you uncomment the command then you have `\scalebox{.50}{\hline}`  but `\hline` can not work inside a box of any sort.

Comment: I am trying to shrink the entire table.

Comment: @sam carter: Neither of these solutions works. The first throws the following error: https://imgur.com/a/zgceW The second kind of works, but at .75 there is overwritten text. How can I scale the entire image so that it fits on the page?

Comment: If `\noindent` before your table solves your problem. That means: `\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xllll}`. It's a duplicat to [Indentation after '\tabular' environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123233/124842). - Always helpful is `\usepackage{showframe}`-> it draws a page-layout diagram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indentation after '\tabular' environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123229/indentation-after-tabular-environments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scale a whole table, by using `\scalebox{0.5}{<table>}`, not with `\scalebox{0.5}` in the middle of it. However, this wouldn't do anything nice, because the table would be scaled to half the linewidth.

This seems a job for `tabulary`, with a patch that David will appreciate.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabulary,array}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\writtenwarning}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Written \\ Warning
  \end{tabular}%
}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\TY@box@v}{\vtop}{$\m@th\vcenter}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\TY@box@v}{$}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{>{\strut}Lllll}
\hline
Type of Violation & 1st & 2nd & 3rd & 4th \\
\hline
Presence without justification, during work hours
in an unauthorized place & 10\% & 25\% & 50\% & 1 day \\    
\hline
Receiving non-work & \writtenwarning & 10\% & 15\% & 25\% \\
\hline
Personal use & \writtenwarning & 10\%   & 25\%    & 50\% \\
\hline
Interference & 50\% & 1 day  & 2 days   & 3 days \\
\hline
Entry/Exit    & \writtenwarning & 10\%   & 15\%    & 25\% \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example compiles on its own, but then I get a: Runaway argument?
\par \par \par \par \cleardoublepage \chapter {Annex No. 6---Model E\ET
! File ended while scanning use of TY@get@body.
<inserted text>
   \par
? "   error. I tried ending the document after the table and the error is there, before the table and the file compiles. So the error is somewhere in the table but I can't see it.

Comment: @user26732 That's because of some syntax error, I guess.

Comment: When I click on "Go to Error" nothing happens. Been at this for over an hour. Any ideas? The file is incomplete so it won't write to log.

Comment: @user26732 No, but you seem to have a macro badly defined somewhere.

Comment: This won't compile; the only macro is the one you suggested. Is there a syntax error there? Did I copy it incorrectly?  I can't paste the shortened file here in a comments box; so here's the image: https://imgur.com/a/aAcAS

Comment: @user26732 You have `\end{tabularly}` instead of `\end{tabulary}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68605/discussion-between-user26732-and-egreg).