# How can I get "block" justification

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like all my paragraph text to not start with indents at beginning of paragraph. And both sides justified against the margin (left and right).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think for indentation you might have a look to [How to disable automatic indentation on new paragraphs?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14375/13304). For justification, you should provide more information: usually a document is justified, however depending on the class used, margins maybe different. Notice that a document can be justified even if left and right margin have different lengths.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino thanks for the link. That filled in the missing pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `\parindent` to `0pt`, you should get full justification.

Answer (score 3):

There's a package for it with a few more options (read its doc). I recommend this solution as it ensures consistency in other lengths that depend on `\parindent`:

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```