# What is the difference between a package and a template in LaTeX?

Tags: macros

I was looking at the post [How to disable automatic indentation on new paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14375/how-to-disable-automatic-indentation-on-new-paragraphs) and the given comments. It was suggested that I go to Ask Question.  Which is what I am doing now.

Somebody was asking there, how paragraph indents may be "disabled without changing the template". But I do not know what that means.  The way I understand it, you cannot change a package by giving various LaTeX-commands inside a .tex-file.  Am I mistaken ?

Comment: You can override commands defined in a package with macros in your document after you have invoked `\usepackage`. You may need `\renewcommand` to do that. There's no official LaTeX "template" - that usually refers to a document class or a package. You're always welcome to ask particular questions here about what you want to do in your document.

Answer (score 5):

A package file is a file (usually of macro definitions) ending in `.sty` that has a specific syntactic use in LaTeX, included with commands such as

```
\usepackage
```

and with internal tests such as

```
\@ifpackageloaded
```

`template` doesn't have a specific meaning in latex itself, it is usually just used to mean an example document that people can use "as a template". Some editors may have a template mechanism to start new documents with some boiler plate code for a letter or a an article or presentation etc, but any such template menu is a feature of the editor not of latex.

Separately The experimental LaTeX3 code has an `xtemplate` package that defines a template declaration mechanism which is using the word with a different meaning,
templates there are a specific way of using a key=value interface do customise environments.

Answer (score 2):

A template consists of predefined layouts, mostly specific for a single purpose, i.e. as a cover or something similar for a thesis etc.

Packages are most times designed to provide general setups which can be used in a multitude of documents (in templates too, of course)

Basically, any setting in a template as well in a package can be overruled (though not advisable) using

- `\def`
- `\renewcommand`
- `\xpatchcmd` (or `\patchcmd`) from `xpatch` or `etoolbox`

More sophicistated approaches use `RenewDocumentCommand` from `xparse` and the features of `LaTeX 3`

Lengths etc. can be set as well with `\setlength` etc. as well counters given new values.

Basically, nothing is really fixed