# "Enter" between paragraphs

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I am using the code

```
\noindent where $rc$ is density ($\rho$) multiplied by heat
capacity ($C_p$), $k$ is thermal conductivity, $h$ is the heat
transfer coefficient, $ambT$ is the ambient temperature, $iniT$
is the initial copper temperature, and $q$ is a heat source
internally supplied to the sample ($\dot{q}$). \\

\noindent Then, the differential equation with boundary and
initial conditions is defined:
```

in the online LaTeX site sharelatex.com. While it *looks* the way I want, it gives the error `Underfill \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph` and I'm not sure how to fix it. I have seen other similar questions, but none of the solutions given seemed to work in my situation. If anyone could help me do it without the error, that'd be great.

Comment: Get rid of the double-backslash at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: And you really shouldn't be using `\noindent`. If you want paragraphs with no indentation separated by blank lines, load the `parskip` package instead.  See [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42)

Comment: Incidentally, the "underfull \hbox" message is a warning message, not an error message.

Comment: Also, $ambT$ looks like the product of $a$, $m$, $b$, and $T$.

Comment: Following up on @JPi's comment: You may want to think about writing the two temperature-related variables `T_{\mathit{amb}}` and `T_{\mathit{ini}}`.

Comment: you might consider using the `parskip` package; see [How to disable automatic indentation on new paragraphs?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27807/579)

Comment: never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph and almost never use `\noindent` in a document.

Comment: @Mico yes it is a warning, but it is warning that the line has badness 10000 which is infinitely bad, as bad as things can  possibly get, so if you ignore that warning you may as well ignore all of them

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, *by definition*, warnings are not as bad as errors (especially fatal errors). I'd agree that it's as bad a problem as an underfull `\hbox` can be. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but the badness level is calculated by how bad this case is in comparison with similar (i.e. underfull `\hbox`) problems, yes?)

Comment: you appear to be starting a paragraph with lowercase `where` which suggests that you have other errrors, such as spurious blank line before the shown code. If `where` was marked up as being part of the current paragraph tex would not indent it and `\noindent` would do nothing.

Comment: @SeanAllred this is particularly bad as although it is reported as an underful hbox (which normaly looks like over stretched word spaces) it _looks_ like vertical space but doesn't behave like space (eg not dropped at a page break)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, there is no need to worry about the lowercase where; this is part of a larger paper, and the where comes after a section of code (in Mathematica; formatted using code from another answer on this site), so the \noindent did take care of the indentation and so did Sean Allred's answer. Thank you for your concerns, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning (not error) is caused by your spurious `\\` at the end of the paragraph. Remove it.

As others have suggested, you also probably want to remove each of the `\noindent`s and load the `parksip` package instead; there are smarter ways of formatting your document than tweaking each paragraph individually.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

% You can customize the vertical space like this:
% \setlength\parskip{1ex}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: What do I do to have a vertical space instead of the \\? I need that space...

Comment: @heather You need to unmarry yourself from the idea that it's an 'enter' to begin with – strictly speaking, it's a vertical space. I'll throw up an MWE in a few minutes and ping you when I'm done.

Comment: Thank you! I added the parksip package and it works beautifully.

Comment: @heather sure thing! See edit for how to customize the vertical space between paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks! It all works properly (and with less code now; this was part of a larger paper with many a \noindent.