# Why this space?

Tags: spacing

How can I delete it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside ,titlepage]{article}

%%% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[label=corner]{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%% settings

%titlesec
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

%geometry
\geometry{a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.4cm,right=2.4cm,heightrounded}

%fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ \ #1}{}}

%caption
\captionsetup{skip=20pt,format=plain,position=bottom,font=small,labelformat=parens,labelfont=bf}

%ulem
\normalem

%hyperref
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

%%%newcommand
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\HRULE}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Bigskip}{\qquad}
\setlocalecaption{italian}{listtable}{Elenco di tabelle, mappe e circuiti}

\title{
\vspace{1.5cm}
\HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.4cm]
\textbf{\Huge\textsc{Progetto\\  Fondamenti di Informatica}} 
\HRULE{1.2pt}\\ [0.8cm]}
\author{\textbf{Nome:} \\ \textbf{Cognome:} \\ 
\textbf{Matricola:} } 
\date{\textbf{Anno Accademico:}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\intextsep}{20pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.png}
    \HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.2cm]
    \Large \texttt{Dipartimento di Ingegneria e Architettura} \\
    \Large\texttt{Ingegneria Eletronica - Informatica} 
\end{figure}

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage


\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}

\section*{Introduzione}
Il proposito di questa introduzione è quello di mostrare i punti chiave del progetto, in modo tale da avere un'idea di come si arriverà all'elaborato finale. \\
Prendendo in considerazione la sola parte numerica della Matricola personale, se ne ricaverà il \emph{resto} dividendo per $ 2^{2^4} $, ed in seguito si provvederà a codificarlo in binario al fine di ottenere una Funzione Booleana associata di 16bit a quattro variabili (x,y,z,w). \\
Quest'ultima verrà rappresentata attraverso l'utilizzo dei termini minimi, \emph{``minterm''}, o dei termini massimi, \emph{``Maxterm''}, termini in cui la Funzione Booleana assume rispettivamente valori 1 e 0, vale a dire dire; la funzione più "complessa" viene rappresentata a partire da funzioni più semplici. \\
Nei passi successivi si provvederà a ricavarne le espressioni e si procederà alla loro semplificazione nel seguente modo:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Per \emph{via algebrica}, attraverso l'utilizzo degli assiomi A1-A7 e dei teoremi T1-T10;
\end{itemize}
A partire dall'espressione semplificata dei Maxterm e attraverso l'utilizzo di assiomi e teoremi, si arriverà a dimostrare che le due espressioni sono del tutto equivalenti, quindi rappresentano la stessa funzione originaria. \\
Nuovamente, si procederà alla semplificazione dell'espressione dei \mbox{minterm} in altri due modi differenti:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Mediante \emph{mappa di Karnaugh};
    \item Metodo \emph{tabellare Quine-Mc Cluskey};
\end{itemize} 
Si potrà constatare che anche le seguenti semplificazioni avranno un risultato pari a quello della semplificazione per via agebrica. \\
Infine, verranno predisposti i disegni degli schemi logici basati su porte \emph{``AND''}, \emph{``OR''} , \emph{``NOT''} della funzione ottenuta dai minterm, dai maxterm e della funzione semplificata. \\
Gli schemi mostreranno, infatti, che lo scopo finale fosse quello di ottenere la forma minima della Funzione Booleana e quindi passare dalla costruzione di un circuito logico più complesso ad uno più semplice, meno costoso, più efficace e con altrettanti molteplici vantaggi.
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduzione}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage

\section{Individuazione Funzione Booleana associata alla \mbox{matricola}}

Acquisito il numero di matricola, si procede nell'individuazione della Funzione Booleana associata; \\

\hspace{12pt}\textbf{Numero Matricola: IN0501032}\\

Elisione del prefisso ``IN'' per ricavarne la sola parte numerica e divisione per $ 2^{2^4} $ affinché se ne ricavi il resto: \\

$ 0501032 \div 2^{2^4} = 501032 \div 65536= 7*65536+42280 $ \\

Il resto è= 42280\\

Codifica del resto in binario tramite divisione per 2, operazione ripetuta per ogni quoziente ottenuto. Il resto di ogni divisione, formato da 0 o 1, comporrà la stringa binaria:

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
$\left.
\begin{array}{r|c}
        42280 & 0\\
        21140 & 0\\
        10570 & 0\\
        5285 & 1\\
        2642 & 0\\
        1321 & 1\\
        660 & 0\\
        330 & 0\\
        165 & 1\\
        82 & 0\\
        41 & 1\\
        20 & 0\\
        10 & 0\\
        5 & 1\\
        2 & 0\\
        1 & 1\\
        0 & /\\
\end{array}
\right\uparrow$
\caption{Codifica del resto in binario}\label{tab:bin} 
\end{table}
\newpage

Il risultato derivante dalla codifica, letto dal basso verso l'alto come indicato dalla freccia della Tabella (\ref{tab:bin}), è il seguente: \\

\hspace{3.5cm} $42280_{10}= \bm{1010010100101000_{2}}$ \\

Si ha, letta dall'alto verso il basso, la Funzione Booleana associata (in grassetto) corrispondente alla stringa binaria ``1010010100101000'':


\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={cccc||c}, 
    column{5}={font=\bfseries}
    }
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $w$ & $\bm{f(x, y, z, w)}$ \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
\end{tblr}
\caption{Tavola di verità della Funzione Booleana associata}\label{tab: Fun} 
\end{table}

Si prosegue rappresentando la Funzione Booleana attraverso l'utilizzo dei termini \mbox{minimi.}

\newpage
 
\section{minterm}
Le funzioni minterm sono rappresentate dai termini in cui la Funzione Boolena assume valore 1. Esse possono essere espresse come prodotto logico di variabili dirette e negate, le prime in corrispondenza delle variabili che in ingresso valgono 1, le seconde in corrispondenza delle variabili che in ingresso valgono 0.\\
Si procede all'identificazione e alla codifica dei termini minimi.

\subsection{Identificazione e codifica dei minterm}

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={c|c||c c c c||c},
    row{2,4,7,9,12,14}={font=\bfseries}
    } 
    & & $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $w$ & $f(x,y,z,w)$ \\
    \hline
    \boldmath$m_0$ & $\bm{\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}}$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    $m_1$ & $\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{z}\:{w}$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    \boldmath$m_2$ & $\bm{\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:{z}\:\overbar{w}}$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    $m_3$ & $\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:{z}\:{w}$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    $m_4$ & $\overbar{x}\:{y}\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \boldmath$m_5$ & $\bm{\overbar{x}\:{y}\:\overbar{z}\:{w}}$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    $m_6$ & $\overbar{x}\:{y}\:{z}\:\overbar{w}$ & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    \boldmath$m_7$ & $\bm{\overbar{x}\:{y}\:{z}\:{w}}$ & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    $m_8$ & ${x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}$ & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    $m_9$ & ${x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{z}\:{w}$ & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    \boldmath$m_{10}$ & $\bm{{x}\:\overbar{y}\:{z}\:\overbar{w}}$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    $m_{11}$ & ${x}\:\overbar{y}\:{z}\:{w}$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    \boldmath$m_{12}$ & $\bm{{x}\:{y}\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}}$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    $m_{13}$ & ${x}\:{y}\:\overbar{z}\:{w}$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    $m_{14}$ & ${x}\:{y}\:{z}\:\overbar{w}$ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    $m_{15}$ & ${x}\:{y}\:{z}\:{w}$ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Codifica dei termini minimi}\label{tab:cod1}
\end{table}

Se ne ricava la Funzione espressa come somma di prodotti:

$\bm{f(x,y,z,w)}=\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}+\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:{z}\:\overbar{w}+\overbar{x}\:{y}\:\overbar{z}\:{w}+\overbar{x}\:{y}\:{z}\:{w}+{x}\:\overbar{y}\:{z}\:\overbar{w}+{x}\:{y}\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}$

\section{Maxterm}
Discorso analogo per quanto riguarda i Maxterm, cioè i termini per i quali la funzione va a 0. \\ Ciò accade nelle quaterne: 0001,0011,0100,0110,1000,1001,1011, 1101,1110,1111, ed il modo più semplice per esprimere un termine Massimo è quello di ricorrere alla somma logica di variabili dirette e negate, le prime in corrispondenza delle variabili che in ingresso valgono 0, le seconde in corrispondenza delle variabili che in ingresso valgono 1.\\
Si procede all'identificazione e alla codifica dei termini minimi.

\subsection{Identificazione e codifica dei Maxterm}
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{%
        colspec={c|c||c c c c||c},
        row{3,5,6,8,10,11,13,15,16,17}={font=\bfseries}
    } 
    & & $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $w$ & $f(x,y,z,w)$ \\
    \hline
    $M_0$ & $x+y+z+w$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    \boldmath$M_1$ & $\bm{x+y+z+\overbar{w}}$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    $M_2$ & $x+y+\overbar{z}+w$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    \boldmath$M_3$ & $\bm{x+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}}$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    \boldmath$M_4$ & $\bm{x+\overbar{y}+z+w}$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    $M_5$ & $x+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    \boldmath$M_6$ & $\bm{x+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w}$ & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    $M_7$ & $x+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}$ & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    \boldmath$M_8$ & $\bm{\overbar{x}+y+z+w}$ & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \boldmath$M_9$ & $\bm{\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w}}$ & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    $M_{10}$ & $\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+w$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    \boldmath$M_{11}$ & $\bm{\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}}$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    $M_{12}$ & $\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+w$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    \boldmath$M_{13}$ & $\bm{\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}}$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    \boldmath$M_{14}$ & $\bm{\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w}$ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    \boldmath$M_{15}$ & $\bm{\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}}$ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Codifica dei termini massimi}\label{tab:cod2}
\end{table}

Se ne ricava la Funzione espressa come prodotto di somme:

$\bm{f=(x,y,z,w)}=(x+y+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w})$


\section{Semplificazione per via algebrica }
Attraverso l'utilizzo degli assiomi A1-A7 e dei teoremi T1-T10, si procede alla semplificazione delle espressioni appena trovate, al fine di ridurre 
\subsection{Semplificazione minterm}
\begin{align*}
    f(x,y,z,w)&= \overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w} + \uwave{\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w}} + \overbar{x}\:y\:\overbar{z}\:w + \overbar{x}\:y\:z\:w + x\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w} + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}= (Per\,T1) \\
    %
    &= \uwave{\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}} + \uwave{\bm{\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w}}} \bm{+ \overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w}} + \overbar{x}\:y\:\overbar{z}\:w + \overbar{x}\:y\:z\:w + x\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w} + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}= (Per\,A6) \\
    %
    &= \bm{\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{w}}\uwave{\bm{(\overbar{z} + z)}} + \overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w} + \overbar{x}\:y\:\overbar{z}\:w + \overbar{x}\:y\:z\:w + x\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w} + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}= (Per\,A7) \\
    %
    &= \uwave{\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{w}\cdot\bm{1}} + \overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w} + \overbar{x}\:y\:\overbar{z}\:w + \overbar{x}\:y\:z\:w + x\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w} + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}= (Per\,A3) \\
    %
    &= \bm{\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{w}} + \uwave{\overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w}} + \overbar{x}\:y\:\overbar{z}\:w + \overbar{x}\:y\:z\:w + \uwave{x\:\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w}} + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}= (Per\,A6) \\
    %
    &= \overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{w} + \bm{\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w}}\uwave{\bm{(\overbar{x} + x)}} + \overbar{x}\:y\:\overbar{z}\:w + \overbar{x}\:y\:z\:w + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}= (Per\,A7) \\
    %
    &= \overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{w} + \uwave{\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w}\cdot\bm{1}} + \overbar{x}\:y\:\overbar{z}\:w + \overbar{x}\:y\:z\:w + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}= (Per\,A3) \\
    %
    &= \overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{w} + \bm{\overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w}} + \uwave{\overbar{x}\:y\:\overbar{z}\:w} + \uwave{\overbar{x}\:y\:z\:w} + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}= (Per\,A6) \\
    %
    &= \overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{w} + \overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w} + \bm{\overbar{x}\:y\:w}\uwave{\bm{(\overbar{z} + z)}} + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}= (Per\,A7) \\
    %
    &= \overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{w} + \overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w} + \uwave{\overbar{x}\:y\:w\cdot\bm{1}} + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}= (Per\,A3) \\
    %
    &= \overbar{x}\:\overbar{y}\:\overbar{w} + \overbar{y}\:z\:\overbar{w} + \bm{\overbar{x}\:y\:w} + x\:y\:\overbar{z}\:\overbar{w}
\end{align*}
\newpage

\subsection{Semplificazione Maxterm}
\begin{align*}
    \hspace{-14mm}f(x,y,w,z)&= \uwave{(x+y+z+\overbar{w})} \cdot \uwave{(x+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w})} \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+w) \\ 
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A6) \\
    %
    &= \bm{[(x+y+\overbar{w})+}\uwave{\bm{(z \cdot \overbar{z})]}} \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot
    (\overbar{x}+y+z+w) \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A7) \\
    %
    &= \uwave{[(x+y+\overbar{w})+\bm{0}]} \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A3) \\
    %
    &= \bm{(x+y+\overbar{w})} \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot \uwave{(x+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w)} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot \uwave{(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w)} \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A6) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot \bm{[(\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w)+}\uwave{\bm{(x \cdot \overbar{x})]}} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+w) \cdot \\ 
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A7) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot \uwave{[(\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w)+\bm{0}]} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+w) \cdot \\ &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A3) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot \bm{(\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w)} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+w) \cdot \\ &\Bigskip\uwave{(\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w})} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, T1) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot \uwave{(\overbar{x}+y+z+w)} \cdot \uwave{\bm{(\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w})}} \bm{\cdot} \\
    &\Bigskip\bm{(\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w})} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A6) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot \bm{[(\overbar{x}+y+z)+} \uwave{\bm{(w \cdot \overbar{w})]}} \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A7) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot \uwave{[(\overbar{x}+y+z)+\bm{0}]} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A3) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot \bm{(\overbar{x}+y+z)} \cdot \uwave{(\overbar{x}+y+z+\overbar{w})} \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip\uwave{(\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w})} \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A6) \\  
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot \bm{[(\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w}) +} \uwave{\bm{(z \cdot \overbar{z})]}} \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A7) 
\end{align*}
\newpage
\begin{align*}
    \hspace{7mm}&= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot \uwave{[(\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w}) + \bm{0}]} \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w}) = (Per\, A3) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot \bm{(\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w})} \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip\uwave{(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+z+\overbar{w})} \cdot \uwave{(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+\overbar{w})} = (Per\, A6) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip\bm{[(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{w})+}\uwave{\bm{(z \cdot{z})]}} = (Per\, A7) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip\uwave{[(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{w})+\bm{0}]} = (Per\, A3) \\
    %
    &= (x+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot \uwave{(\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w})} \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip\bm{(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{w})} = (Per\, T1) \\
    %
    &= \uwave{(x+y+\overbar{w})} \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot \uwave{\bm{(\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w})}} \bm{\cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w})} \cdot \\
    &\Bigskip(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{w})= (Per\, A6) \\
    %
    &= \bm{[(y+\overbar{w})+} \uwave{\bm{(x \cdot \overbar{x})]}} \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot  \\
    &\Bigskip (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{w})= (Per\, A7) \\
    %
    &= \uwave{[(y+\overbar{w})+ \bm{0]}} \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w}) \cdot  \\
    &\Bigskip (\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{w})= (Per\, A3) \\
    %
    &= \bm{(y+\overbar{w})} \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot \uwave{(\overbar{x}+y+\overbar{w})} \cdot \uwave{(\overbar{x}+\overbar{y}+\overbar{w})}= (Per\, A6) \\
    %
    &= (y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot \bm{[(\overbar{x}+\overbar{w})+} \uwave{\bm{(y \cdot \overbar{y})]}}= (Per\, A7) \\
    %
    &= (y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+z+w) \cdot (\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot \uwave{[(\overbar{x}+\overbar{w})+ \bm{0]}}= (Per\, A3) \\
    %
    &= (y+\overbar{w}) \cdot \uwave{(x+\overbar{y}+z+w)} \cdot \uwave{(\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w)} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z) \cdot \uwave{\bm{(\overbar{x}+\overbar{w})}}= (Per\, A4) \\
    %
    &= (y+\overbar{w}) \cdot \bm{(\overbar{x}+\overbar{w})} \cdot \uwave{\bm{(\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w)}} \cdot \uwave{\bm{(x+\overbar{y}+z+w)}} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z)= (Per\, A6) \\
    %
    &= (y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{w}) \cdot \bm{[(\overbar{y}+w)+} \uwave{\bm{[\overbar{z} \cdot (x+z)]}} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z)= (Per\, T5) \\
    %
    &= (y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{w}) \cdot \uwave{[(\overbar{y}+w)+\bm{(\overbar{z} \cdot x)]}} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z)= (Per\, A6) \\
    %
    &= (y+\overbar{w}) \cdot (\overbar{x}+\overbar{w}) \cdot \bm{(\overbar{y}+\overbar{z}+w) \cdot (x+\overbar{y}+w)} \cdot (\overbar{x}+y+z)
\end{align*}
\newpage
\section{Mappa di Karnaugh}

\begin{karnaugh-map}*[4][4][1][xy][zw]
    
    \manualterms{1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0}
    \implicant{5}{13}
    \implicant{3}{3}
    \implicantedge{0}{0}{8}{8}
    \implicantedge{8}{8}{10}{10}
    
\end{karnaugh-map}


\begin{karnaugh-map}*[4][4][1][xy][zw]
    
    \manualterms{1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0}
    \implicant{5}{13}
    \implicant{3}{3}
    \implicant{10}{10}
    \implicantedge{0}{0}{8}{8}
    

\end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cabohah look now, please

Comment: Please note, you should not use \\ in justified text. To print displayed equations you should use an environment for displayed equations, e.g. `\[ 0501032 \div 2^{2^4} = 501032 \div 65536= 7*65536+42280 \]`. For more information about displayed equations and text inside equations, please have a look into [the `amsmath` user manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/amsmath/0).

Comment: You should also not use physical markup for something like a heading, e.g., `\hspace{12pt}\textbf{Numero Matricola: IN0501032}\\ `, but use a heading, e.g. `\subsubsection*{Numero Matricola: IN0501032}` or `\paragraph{Numero Matricola: IN0501032}` or another environment like `description`, depending on the intention of the `\hspace{…}\textbf{…}`.

Comment: @cabohah check it now, please

Comment: Please make your document example much shorter!

Comment: These are the paragraph indent. You can, e.g., use [package `parskip`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) to remove them.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14375/how-to-disable-automatic-indentation-on-new-paragraphs

Comment: @cabohah I solved!! Grazieee milleeee!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the standard paragraph indentation.

My impression is that you are using LaTeX like a word processor. No, it isn't.

Here's a version of the first section in a better shape. I recommend to avoid all explicit spacing instructions (only sometimes they're needed) and to restrain from “blank lines in output”: the paragraph indentation serves the same purpose and makes for a better flow in the text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside ,titlepage]{article}

%%% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm,tabularray}

\begin{document}

\section{Individuazione Funzione Booleana associata alla \mbox{matricola}}

Acquisito il numero di matricola, si procede nell'individuazione della 
Funzione Booleana associata
\begin{center}
\textbf{Numero Matricola: IN0501032}
\end{center}
Elisione del prefisso ``IN'' per ricavarne la sola parte numerica e divisione per 
$ 2^{2^4} $ affinché se ne ricavi il resto:
\[
0501032 \div 2^{2^4} = 501032 \div 65536= 7*65536+42280
\]
Il resto è $42280$.

Codifica del resto in binario tramite divisione per 2, operazione ripetuta 
per ogni quoziente ottenuto. Il resto di ogni divisione, formato da 0 o 1, 
comporrà la stringa binaria secondo la tabella~\ref{tab:bin}.

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
$\left.
\begin{array}{r|c}
        42280 & 0\\
        21140 & 0\\
        10570 & 0\\
        5285 & 1\\
        2642 & 0\\
        1321 & 1\\
        660 & 0\\
        330 & 0\\
        165 & 1\\
        82 & 0\\
        41 & 1\\
        20 & 0\\
        10 & 0\\
        5 & 1\\
        2 & 0\\
        1 & 1\\
        0 & /\\
\end{array}
\right\uparrow$
\caption{Codifica del resto in binario}\label{tab:bin} 
\end{table}

Il risultato derivante dalla codifica, letto dal basso verso l'alto come 
indicato dalla freccia della tabella~(\ref{tab:bin}), è il seguente:
\[
42280_{10}= \bm{1010010100101000_{2}}
\]
Si ha, letta dall'alto verso il basso, la Funzione Booleana associata 
(in grassetto) corrispondente alla stringa binaria ``1010010100101000''
come nella tabella~\ref{tab:Fun}.


\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={cccc||c}, 
    column{5}={font=\bfseries}
    }
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $w$ & $\bm{f(x, y, z, w)}$ \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
\end{tblr}
\caption{Tavola di verità della Funzione Booleana associata}\label{tab:Fun} 
\end{table}

Si prosegue rappresentando la Funzione Booleana attraverso l'utilizzo dei termini \mbox{minimi.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even in everyone's favorite *word* processor ↵ doesn't input a ``\\`` but a `\par`. OP used LaTeX like a typewriter.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Perhaps because many people use word processor like typewriters (how to center a line?, type spaces at the beginning).

Answer (score 2):

If you want delete the indent spacing, you can add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`.

[image]

See compiling your MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside ,titlepage]{article}

%%% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[label=corner]{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%% settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%<-----------------added!!
%titlesec
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

%geometry
\geometry{a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.4cm,right=2.4cm,heightrounded}

%fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ \ #1}{}}

%caption
\captionsetup{skip=20pt,format=plain,position=bottom,font=small,labelformat=parens,labelfont=bf}

%ulem
\normalem

%hyperref
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

%%%newcommand
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\HRULE}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Bigskip}{\qquad}
\setlocalecaption{italian}{listtable}{Elenco di tabelle, mappe e circuiti}

\title{
\vspace{1.5cm}
\HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.4cm]
\textbf{\Huge\textsc{Progetto\\  Fondamenti di Informatica}} 
\HRULE{1.2pt}\\ [0.8cm]}
\author{\textbf{Nome:} \\ \textbf{Cognome:} \\ 
\textbf{Matricola:} } 
\date{\textbf{Anno Accademico:}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\intextsep}{20pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-B.png}
    \HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.2cm]
    \Large \texttt{Dipartimento di Ingegneria e Architettura} \\
    \Large\texttt{Ingegneria Eletronica - Informatica} 
\end{figure}

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage


\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}

\section*{Introduzione}
Il proposito di questa introduzione è quello di mostrare i punti chiave del progetto, in modo tale da avere un'idea di come si arriverà all'elaborato finale. \\
Prendendo in considerazione la sola parte numerica della Matricola personale, se ne ricaverà il \emph{resto} dividendo per $ 2^{2^4} $, ed in seguito si provvederà a codificarlo in binario al fine di ottenere una Funzione Booleana associata di 16bit a quattro variabili (x,y,z,w). \\
Quest'ultima verrà rappresentata attraverso l'utilizzo dei termini minimi, \emph{``minterm''}, o dei termini massimi, \emph{``Maxterm''}, termini in cui la Funzione Booleana assume rispettivamente valori 1 e 0, vale a dire dire; la funzione più "complessa" viene rappresentata a partire da funzioni più semplici. \\
Nei passi successivi si provvederà a ricavarne le espressioni e si procederà alla loro semplificazione nel seguente modo:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Per \emph{via algebrica}, attraverso l'utilizzo degli assiomi A1-A7 e dei teoremi T1-T10;
\end{itemize}
A partire dall'espressione semplificata dei Maxterm e attraverso l'utilizzo di assiomi e teoremi, si arriverà a dimostrare che le due espressioni sono del tutto equivalenti, quindi rappresentano la stessa funzione originaria. \\
Nuovamente, si procederà alla semplificazione dell'espressione dei \mbox{minterm} in altri due modi differenti:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Mediante \emph{mappa di Karnaugh};
    \item Metodo \emph{tabellare Quine-Mc Cluskey};
\end{itemize} 
Si potrà constatare che anche le seguenti semplificazioni avranno un risultato pari a quello della semplificazione per via agebrica. \\
Infine, verranno predisposti i disegni degli schemi logici basati su porte \emph{``AND''}, \emph{``OR''} , \emph{``NOT''} della funzione ottenuta dai minterm, dai maxterm e della funzione semplificata. \\
Gli schemi mostreranno, infatti, che lo scopo finale fosse quello di ottenere la forma minima della Funzione Booleana e quindi passare dalla costruzione di un circuito logico più complesso ad uno più semplice, meno costoso, più efficace e con altrettanti molteplici vantaggi.
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduzione}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage

\section{Individuazione Funzione Booleana associata alla \mbox{matricola}}

Acquisito il numero di matricola, si procede nell'individuazione della Funzione Booleana associata; \\

\hspace{12pt}\textbf{Numero Matricola: IN0501032}\\

Elisione del prefisso ``IN'' per ricavarne la sola parte numerica e divisione per $ 2^{2^4} $ affinché se ne ricavi il resto: \\

$ 0501032 \div 2^{2^4} = 501032 \div 65536= 7*65536+42280 $ \\

Il resto è= 42280\\

Codifica del resto in binario tramite divisione per 2, operazione ripetuta per ogni quoziente ottenuto. Il resto di ogni divisione, formato da 0 o 1, comporrà la stringa binaria:

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
$\left.
\begin{array}{r|c}
        42280 & 0\\
        21140 & 0\\
        10570 & 0\\
        5285 & 1\\
        2642 & 0\\
        1321 & 1\\
        660 & 0\\
        330 & 0\\
        165 & 1\\
        82 & 0\\
        41 & 1\\
        20 & 0\\
        10 & 0\\
        5 & 1\\
        2 & 0\\
        1 & 1\\
        0 & /\\
\end{array}
\right\uparrow$
\caption{Codifica del resto in binario}\label{tab:bin} 
\end{table}
\newpage


\end{document}
```