# Too much whitespace before lists when changing the \parskip length

Tags: spacing, lists, parskip

I have the following in my preamble:

```
\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0 pt}
```

Now there is too much whitespace before an `enumerate` list environment, in the example I have put an `\mbox{}` but it is the same with text. How do I decrease it without hacks like
`\hspace{1mm}\\[-10mm]`?

Comment: "A solution to (nuke) is an "integral solution" to (more nukes)"?

Comment: @Martin: Yes. It is an important equation :P.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Would you mind reuploading the image using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G)? The server [it is hosted on](http://www.cgti.nl/gf/mbox.png) seems to be down right now.

Comment: @diabonas: Unfortunately, I could't find the it anymore. I have deleted it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually a "conceptual bug" in LaTeX: `\parskip` is added before and after lists, even when they don't start/end a paragraph. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/increasing-paragraph-indentation-in-koma-script/14565#14565) answer for details.

Solution: Don't change the `\parskip` length, but load the [`parskip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package or use one of the [`KOMA-script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes or [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir).

Comment: Which one would you recommend: `parskip` or the `KOMA-script` classes?

Comment: @Jonas: I recommend the KOMA-script classes -- be aware, however, that their default page layout is different from that of the standard classes.

Answer (score 7):

Changing `\parindent` and `\parskip` is considered as one of the "deadly sins" in [l2tabu](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english) and should be avoided. You can use the [parskip](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package, or one of the options provided by the KOMA-Script document classes.

However, if you decide to continue with the modifications to `\parskip` and `\parindent`, you can reduce the vertical space before and after the list by loading the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and using `\setenumerate` to change the value of `topsep`; simply add these lines to the preamble of your document (using the value that best suits your needs):

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setenumerate{topsep=-\baselineskip}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me that it is a "deadly sin", I'll use the `parskip` package.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom In the next sentence, the asker's example is almost explicitly listed as _do not use_.

Comment: @mfloren I should have been more clear and careful. I was personally using `\setlength{\parindent}{0 em}`, without changing `\parskip`. It seems that changing `\parskip` is what is really evil. I suppose I interpreted this answer as saying: "Never change either one of `\parindent` or `\parskip`". But I suppose the answerer is saying that this combination of changes is bad, as does his reference. This makes sense as the OP also uses the combination.

Comment: With `enumitem` and the KOMAoptions `parskip`, I use `\setlist{nosep,topsep=-\parskip}`

Answer (score 1):

After `\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` in the preamble

```
\begin{enumerate}\setlength{\itemsep}{-\baselineskip} 
 \item  good
 \item  bad
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: I agree with the remarks about changing `\parindent` and `\parskip`.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like it is bad practice to do so.

Comment: You can prefer to  have a null indent but to add space to the parskip. It's a typography choice. After the problem is to know the side effects. For example in a mathematics exam it's sometimes useful to change `itemsep` if you use `enumerate` to ask questions. But the use of parskip package is better solution.