# How can I align my list (enumerate) with the start of my paragraph?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I am having an issue aligning the left side of my list with the left side of my paragraph. Here is my current code:

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[draft, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\parindent = 0pt

\begin{document}

This is a random and long sentence that apparently takes up two lines just so that I 
can see what happens with alignment and indentation. Note my \texttt{parindent = 0pt}.

\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is list one first item.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin = 0pt]
    \item This is list two first item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Visual representation:**

This is a random and long sentence that apparently takes up two lines just so that I can see 
      what happens with alignment and indentation. Note my parindent = 0pt.

1.  This is list one first item.

1.  This is list two first item.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution depends on how many items you are expecting in the list. If the number of items is 9 or less than use:

```
labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=0.75em,leftmargin=!
```

but for 10 thru 99 you should use a larger `labelwidth=1.25em`

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.
- Manually setting `\parskip` is considered a "deadly sin" as per [Too much whitespace before lists when changing the \parskip length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14768/4301). Use [the `parskip` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) instead.
- A good reference for the horizontal spacing parameters is [can someone please explain the enumitem horizontal spacing parameters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184780/can-someone-please-explain-the-enumitem-horizontal-spacing-parameters).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[draft, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\parindent = 0pt
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}% Use this instead of \parindent = 0pt

\begin{document}

This is a random and long sentence that apparently takes up two lines just so that I 
can see what happens with alignment and indentation. Previously \verb|parindent = 0pt|, but
now this uses the \verb|parskip| package.

\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=1.25em,leftmargin=!]
    \item This is list one first item.
    \item This is list one second item.
    \item \ldots
    \item[9.] This is list one ninth item.
    \item[10.] This is list one tenth item.
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip
If you don't expect to go past 9 then use:
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=0.75em,leftmargin=!]
    \item This is list two first item.
    \item \ldots
    \item[9.] This is list two ninth item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `ex`? I thought the best unit for this was `em`.

Comment: @egreg: "I thought?" You are too modest :-)  Fixing now...

Comment: Thanks @PeterGrill! Upon reviewing your code, it got me to look into `showframe` (something I was wondering how to do), the `parskip` package, and the link on spacing. My question is, if I use `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` what changes does `\noindent` make? Maybe I didn't catch it, but I couldn't figure out the difference between including `\noindent` and removing it.

Comment: The `\noindent` is not needed, and have removed it in the MWE.

Comment: Also, what about using `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` versus just `\usepackage{parskip}`? I didn't seem to find a difference.

Comment: @dahiana: As the thrust of this question was about aligning list items, you should post a new question on `parskip`.  We like to keep it to one question per post as then the answers are easier to find and more likely to be of help to a larger audience.

Comment: no problem, I just wanted to clarify some other questions. Nonetheless, this was exactly what I was looking for! The `labelindent`, `labelwidth`, and `leftmargin` options really helped. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You also can have item numbers left aligned, and thus aligned withe the left side of the text area, using the `wide` option:

```
\documentclass[draft, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

This is a random and long sentence that apparently takes up two lines just so that I
can see what happens with alignment and indentation.

\noindent
\begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt, labelwidth = 1.3333em, labelsep = 0.3333em, leftmargin = \dimexpr\labelwidth + \labelsep\relax ]%
    \item This is list one first item.
    \item This is list one second item.
    \item \ldots
    \item[9.] \lipsum[9]
    \item[10.] \lipsum[10]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I actually really like this version too. Thank you so much for pointing out the `wide` option. I think I'll play around with it and see what works best.