# How to give double line spacing between paragraphs?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, line-spacing

I am preparing my thesis with single line spaced, but it needs double line spacing between paragraphs. I am using `\\` at the end of paragraph to achieve this. How to do this by using `\parskip` package for the whole document?

```
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In a distributed database system, data is replicate of the most important advantages of replication is that it masks and tolerates failures in the network     gracefully and increases availability. \\

In case of multiple access a problem that must be solved while using replication is about maintaining the a generalization of the majority consensus method presented in\\

 This protocol can be viewed as specialized version of ring and tree    protocol.
 As compared to other protocols, wheel protocol can be used for arbitrary     number of nodes.

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you looked at: [Vertical Space Between Paragraphs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/how-to-insert-vertical-space-between-paragraphs)?

Comment: Never end a paragraph with `\\ ` it generates underfull hbox warnings and the warnings shouldn't be ignored it makes very poor output that does entirely the wrong thing at page breaks (and other places)

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{2\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In a distributed database system, data is replicate of the most important advantages of replication is that it masks and tolerates failures in the network     gracefully and increases availability. 

In case of multiple access a problem that must be solved while using replication is about maintaining the a generalization of the majority consensus method presented in

 This protocol can be viewed as specialized version of ring and tree    protocol.
 As compared to other protocols, wheel protocol can be used for arbitrary     number of nodes.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> \setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

to achieve a custom `\parskip` in your whole document. Adjust the value to your needs and place the command inside your `document`-environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to the top of your file:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
```

This way, the spacing will automatically update based upon the font size you choose.

Here is a MWE:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

In a distributed database system, data is replicate of the most important advantages of replication is that it masks and tolerates failures in the network     gracefully and increases availability.

In case of multiple access a problem that must be solved while using replication is about maintaining the a generalization of the majority consensus method presented in

This protocol can be viewed as specialized version of ring and tree protocol.
As compared to other protocols, wheel protocol can be used for arbitrary number of nodes.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use `\\` at the end of a paragraph and do not change the `\parskip` manually (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14565/43317).

You could load package `parskip`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
In a distributed database system, data is replicate of the most important advantages of replication is that it masks and tolerates failures in the network     gracefully and increases availability. 

In case of multiple access a problem that must be solved while using replication is about maintaining the a generalization of the majority consensus method presented in

This protocol can be viewed as specialized version of ring and tree    protocol.
As compared to other protocols, wheel protocol can be used for arbitrary     number of nodes.

 \end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or you could use a **KOMA-Script class** with option `parskip=full-`:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full-]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In a distributed database system, data is replicate of the most important advantages of replication is that it masks and tolerates failures in the network gracefully and increases availability. 

In case of multiple access a problem that must be solved while using replication is about maintaining the a generalization of the majority consensus method presented in

This protocol can be viewed as specialized version of ring and tree    protocol.
As compared to other protocols, wheel protocol can be used for arbitrary     number of nodes.

\end{document}
```

See the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) to find more possible values for option `parskip`.

If you want to use a parskip that differs from `half` or `full` you can use the command `\setparsizes{<parindent>}{<parskip>}{<horizontal white space at the end of a paragraph>}`.

Example with a `parskip` of `2\baselineskip`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setparsizes{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{0pt plus 1fill}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In a distributed database system, data is replicate of the most important advantages of replication is that it masks and tolerates failures in the network     gracefully and increases availability. 

In case of multiple access a problem that must be solved while using replication is about maintaining the a generalization of the majority consensus method presented in

This protocol can be viewed as specialized version of ring and tree    protocol.
As compared to other protocols, wheel protocol can be used for arbitrary     number of nodes.

\end{document}
```

If `parskip` should depend on the fontsize you can try option `parskip=relative` additionally:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full-,parskip=relative]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In a distributed database system, data is replicate of the most important advantages of replication is that it masks and tolerates failures in the network     gracefully and increases availability. 

In case of multiple access a problem that must be solved while using replication is about maintaining the a generalization of the majority consensus method presented in

This protocol can be viewed as specialized version of ring and tree    protocol.
As compared to other protocols, wheel protocol can be used for arbitrary     number of nodes.

\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}
\tiny
In a distributed database system, data is replicate of the most important advantages of replication is that it masks and tolerates failures in the network     gracefully and increases availability. 

In case of multiple access a problem that must be solved while using replication is about maintaining the a generalization of the majority consensus method presented in

This protocol can be viewed as specialized version of ring and tree    protocol.
As compared to other protocols, wheel protocol can be used for arbitrary     number of nodes.
\end{document}
```

[image]