# How do I add vertical margins to a paragraph (selectively, so not applying to all paragraphs)?

Tags: spacing, margins, paragraphs

For some typesetting, I want to add vertical margins (top and bottom) around certain paragraphs. I already found the package `changepage` and their environment `adjustwidth` to set the horizontal margins (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594).

However, I am not sure, how to achieve vertical margins.

Possibly through `parskip` or `\\\\` (also see [How to insert vertical space between paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/how-to-insert-vertical-space-between-paragraphs)). However, I want it to be robust, and ideally apply it to a paragraph with an environment.

I hope, there is a nice way for this.

Comment: `bigskip, \medskip`, `\vspace{ }`, of `\\[40mm]`. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#Fixed-length_spaces

Comment: `\newenvironment{\myenv}{\bigskip}{\bigskip}` as @MS-SPO just implied. Exchange `bigskip` with any length you want

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the answer. I'll test, but am rather certain that it'll work. Feel free to post as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building from the comments, I came up with:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{verticalmargins}{mm}{\vspace{#1}}{\vspace{#2}}
```

This allows to specify margins separately for top and bottom (which is why I use `xparse`, as `\newenvironment` doesn't allow access of arguments in the second bracket for the code to be executed after the environment).

Comment: If your installation of TeX is recent, you don't need `xparse`.