# New paragraph without \newline?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

I am writing on a larger text and sometimes I want to begin a new paragraph. So I don't want to have a new heading, just a space for visiual reasons. Currently I use the solution with `\\ \newline`

For example:

```
Here is my text text text and now I finish this thought. 
\\ \newline 
Here I begin with another aspect....
 text text
```

Another solution I can imagine is with vspace, but this is also not really professional, so how should I do this?

Comment: Don't end paragraphs with ``\\``, but leaving an empty line between them. If you *really* want a vertical space between two paragraphs (but this is rarely necessary or useful), type `\medskip` after the empty line and before the new paragraph. An empty line after `\medskip` is optional (but good).

Comment: @egreg this is not helping me. If I just put in an empty line I do NOT get a new paragraph in my pdf file? It just goes on in the next line, but there is no space between it? This is not a substitute for \\ \newline ? This is just like \\

Comment: @egreg \medskip is not big enough

Comment: @StatTistician You sound like you want blank lines between paragraphs: the typographic tradition adopted 'out of the box' by LaTeX is to have an indent for the first line of each paragraph with no gap. Try `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}`.

Comment: Then use `\bigskip` (but my advice is just doing a new paragraph).

Comment: @egreg thanks, but what do you mean with "just doing a new paragraph" ? Just add an empty line in my latex editor? This gives really almost no space between the paragraphs in my pdf document?

Comment: @StatTistician Take some books from your shelf and look at them: how many have big spacing between paragraphs?

Comment: @egreg at least more space than what I get with just an empty line?

Comment: @StatTistician Not in the books I have on my shelf. In my 716 page Penguin edition of *David Copperfield* there's *no* vertically spaced paragraph. Vertical spacing is used only for chapter starts and when reporting letters.

Comment: @egreg but I mean, I just wanted to have a new visual separation, so a new thought is starting. It is not part of the next paragraph, but it also does not connect strongly to the previous part?

Comment: @StatTistician Then use `\bigskip` (but `\medskip` is less invasive). But I assure you that readers are able to see by themselves that a change of thought has happened.

Comment: I guess that the OP is trying to do something similar to `foooooo\linebreak[1cm]foooooo`, that is, just a vertical space between two lines, without indentation.

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned in the comments, you should not end paragraphs by `\\ \newline`, but rather leave an empty line between the paragraphs. Of course, as with many rules there may be an occasion where it is better not to respect it, but these cases are rare.

If you wish to have ALL of your paragraphs separated by more space, you can use `\parskip = 10pt` (or some other length) in the preamble. There are also some packages that can do this.

Comment: It is bad practice to simply change the `\parskip` length; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14565/510