# Vertical spacing in KOMA-script

Tags: spacing, koma-script, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

How can I change vertical spacing (and indents) of `\paragraph`, list and list item elements in KOMA-script article class? Is there some canonical way to do this?

[image: i need]

I've tried to use `titlesec` package, but it doesn't change `\paragraph` vertical space.

Comment: A compilable example is always welcome so we have something to start with. In any case, you can customize spacing with `enumitem` package (for the list) and with `\RedeclareSectionCommand` (for the `\paragraph` spacing).

Comment: @Manuel Thanks. I made so, and everything works fine (almost).

Comment: Except for the minimal compilable example :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question. The OP must have changed something regarding the `\paragraph` definition because with the original definition there would be some space inserted before the paragraph heading.

Here is an example using `enumitem` and `\RedeclareSectionCommand` as suggested by @Manuel in a comment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{label=-,leftmargin=*,nosep,after=\medskip}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip
]{paragraph}

\setlength\parindent{2em}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only dummy text
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\paragraph{paragraph text}
\begin{myitemize}
  \item list item 1
  \item list item 2
  \item list item 3
\end{myitemize}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there are a lot of implicit questions here.

1. If you want to play with the paragraphs' indentation, set the length for said indentation with `\setlength{parindent}{size}`, where `size` means either pt, mm, in, or any other length dimension.  If you want no indentation, type the `\noindent` command at the beginning of the paragraph.
2. If you want to play with the paragraphs' separation between them, set the amount of space with `\setlength{parskip}{size}`, where `size` mean either pt, mm, in or any other length dimension.  Although playing with `parskip` doesn't seem to be a good idea.  Check here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14565/27833
3. If you want to play with the amount of space between text lines, I suggest you take a look at the [`setspace`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package, and use something like `\onehalfspacing` for issuing more space between them.
4. For separation between `item` in an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment, take a look at the [`enumitem package`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en).  You can set up the amount of space with the `itemsep` option.  Run the code below to see all the examples I mentioned.

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem} %For list environments
\usepackage{setspace} %For line spacing

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %For dummy text

\begin{document}

%Normal spacing between text lines 
\kant[1]

%One and half spacing between text lines 
\onehalfspacing
\kant[1]

%No indentation 
\noindent \kant[1]

%Lots of indentation 
\setlength{\parindent}{30mm} 
\kant[1]

%More vertical space between paragraphs (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14565/27833)
\setlength{\parskip}{20mm}

\kant[1]

\kant[1]

\begin{itemize}[itemsep={20mm}]

\item hola1 
\item hola2 
\item hola3

\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not change `\parskip` manually (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14565/43317). There is a `parskip` option with different values (see the documentation) for the KOMA-Script classes. Or if you need really special settings you can use the KOMA-Script command `\setparsizes{<indent>}{<distance>}{<last line end space>}`.

Answer (score 0):

Without MWE difficult to say. What about this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{paralist, blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section*{You get}
\label{CLA:you-get}

\blindtext

\paragraph{paragraph text}

\begin{compactitem}
  \item list item 1
  \item list item 2
  \item list item 3
\end{compactitem}
\bigskip

\blindtext{}

\end{document}
```